# Random based upon percentage

Tags: random, lua, logic, percentage

Given a set a yet unknown values in an array/table,  where each value contains a number, how would I make it so that the values with higher numbers have a larger chance of being picked?

I did this in Lua and I came up with an extremely inefficient method that didn't even work some reason:

Example:

```
"module.InsertTokens(5,'a')
--The function above would insert the value "a" five times into an array
module.RemoveId('a') --this is supposed to remove all values of a
print(#module.Tokens)"
```

> 2
>   --should be 0
>   --why does it return 2?? D:

```
function module.InsertTokens(amount, id)
    for i = 1, amount do --amount times
        print'inserting'
        module.Tokens[#module.Tokens+1]=id
    end
end

function module.RemoveId(id)
for index, v in pairs(module.Tokens) do 
    if v == id then
        print'removing' 
        table.remove(module.Tokens, index)
    end 
end
end
```

Is there some sort of algorithm or better logic I can use?
(Also if you can, point out what I did wrong with the code above?)

Comment: You can't modify a table you are iterating over with `pairs`. It is undefined. See the manual entry for [next](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next).

Comment: To do what you tried to do there you would likely want to just create a new table from the values that don't match your id. Unless your table is *huge* that will likely be the simplest and reasonably performant solution.

Comment: Like this?

function module.RemoveId(id)
 print(#module.Tokens)
 for index, v in next,module.Tokens do 
  if v == id then
   print'removing'
   table.remove(module.Tokens, index)
  end 
 end
end

Comment: Oh wait okay, didn't see your second comment

Comment: replace `for index, v in pairs(module.Tokens) do ... end` with `for index = #module.Tokens,1,-1 do if module.Tokens[i]==id then ... end end`

Comment: Can you guys conceive of a more efficient method though :/

Comment: (For random based percentage)

Comment: the [Alias Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) is efficient. It requires building a table in O(n) and then you get constant time sampling.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the value into the table as many times as it's percent. For example if you want "a" to have 95% chance and "b" to have 5, put a in the table 95 times, and b in there 5 times